# Erratic contents of UITextField as subviews of table cells when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm trying to add a `UITextField` as a subview to my table cells.  The content of the text fields is fine until I start scrolling and the cells start to be reused.  The images illustrate the problem.

[image: first screenshot] [image: second screenshot] [image: third screenshot]

At first, the blue values on the right in the `UITextField` are correct, i.e. the value corresponds to the row number.  The second and third images, scrolled down and back up, show that the values are being reused in odd ways.

How do I avoid this?  Using unique values for `reuseIdentifier` solves this problem, but obviously it's not very efficient.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITextField *numberTextField;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        numberTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 95, 30)];
        numberTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        numberTextField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        numberTextField.placeholder = @"Enter value";
        numberTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
        numberTextField.tag = ([indexPath row]+1);
        numberTextField.backgroundColor = [cell backgroundColor];
        numberTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        numberTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        numberTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        [numberTextField setEnabled:YES];

        [cell addSubview:numberTextField];

    } else {
        numberTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:([indexPath row]+1)];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %i",[indexPath row]+1];
    numberTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value: %i",[indexPath row]+1];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only assign the tag to the numberTextField when it is created.  If it gets reused, it doesn't get its tag reassigned.

You should use a constant tag number for the UITextField instead of using row+1.

Comment: I use the tag to reference the field later on when I need to get the value that has been entered.  Is there a better way of accessing that value?  I use something like the following code when the user is done editing:     UITextField *tf;    tf=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];    variableName = [f numberFromString:tf.text];

Comment: One thing I've found that works is storing all the required `UITextField`s in an array.  That way I can give them all a constant tag and still refer to them later.  Is that an inefficient use of an array?  I may have up to 50-100 of them in some cases.

Comment: You should not store data in views!  You are violating the MVC design.  What you should do is: create a textfield when you create the cell.  When the textfield stops editing, take its string and put it in a model class. In cellForRowAtIndexPath just reuse the textfield that already exists, and set its value to the value of the string from the model.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself very well, because I'm doing exactly what you've suggested.  Reusing the existing textfield was giving me the issue in the first place.  I ended up subclassing UITableViewCell and added the textfield on init there.  Seems to be working well.

Comment: the code you pasted above does not do what you describe.  the cell reuse is messing you up there.  glad you got it sorted though!  using subclasses is generally the better way to go in these situations anyway.